# Mapping from n to m

Tags: xslt, nodes

My problem is that i want to move nodes in the XML to nodes that occur after them f.eks:
I have a xml that looks like this:

```
<root>
   <node>a</node>
   <node>b</node>
   <node>c</node>
   <top1>
   <node>d</node>
   <node>e</node>
   <top2>
</root>
```

And it shall end up as

```
<root>
   <top1>
     <node>a</node>
     <node>b</node>
     <node>c</node>
   </top1>
   <top2>
     <node>d</node>
     <node>e</node>
   </top2>
</root>
```

But i haven't got any xsl that can do this. I have given it some tries with using position() but none of it gets me closer.
Can anybody show me the right approach

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Also, the input XML you posted is invalid - some nodes are missing closing tags or should be self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

**XML Input** (corrected to be well-formed)

```
<root>
    <node>a</node>
    <node>b</node>
    <node>c</node>
    <top1/>
    <node>d</node>
    <node>e</node>
    <top2/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[starts-with(name(),'top')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'top')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|preceding-sibling::node[(following-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'top')])[1][generate-id() = generate-id(current())]]"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <top1>
      <node>a</node>
      <node>b</node>
      <node>c</node>
   </top1>
   <top2>
      <node>d</node>
      <node>e</node>
   </top2>
</root>
```

Comment: But i forgot one "detail" - there is elements in the "top" nodes already that shall stay there. As described in the following.

Comment: @user1518851 Add `<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>` inside the last `<xsl:copy>`

Answer (score 0):

My input is like this:
This does not work with the xsl above - it removes the kids in the top elements.

```
<root>
    <node>a</node>
    <node>b</node>
    <node>c</node>
    <top1>
       <node>1</node>
       <node>2</node>
    </top1>
    <node>d</node>
    <node>e</node>
    <top2>
       <node>3</node>
       <node>4</node>
    </top2>
</root>
```

Comment: i found a solution - it is just a matter of applying 
<xsl:apply-templates select "*"/>